# Access Office 365 Calendar for Other Domain Users in Company

Tags: c#, powershell, outlook, office365

In Outlook and 365 online I successfully can browse out and view the calendars of others in my company.

How can I access their calendar programatically? I've tried something like:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/domainuser@mycompany.com/ca
lendarview?startDateTime=$(Get-Date)&endDateTime=$((Get-Date).AddDays(7))" -Credential (Get-Credential) | foreach-object
{ $_.Value }
```

But it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 REST API uses OAuth to gain permission for accessing Office 365 data, so for a multiple tenants app, customers don’t have to register the app in other tenants, but only need users in those tenants to grant permission in a consent flow. so your employees in your tenant can use it by logging into your company's Azure AD tenant but other company users can also login to their Azure AD and use your company's app.  But users in your tenant can’t get other company user’s data in a multi-tenant app .